# Adding library dependency in play 2.3.8

Tags: plugins, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to add the apache commons email library to my Play project and I'm having trouble.

Firstly I have both build.sbt and plugins.sbt in my project and I'm not sure which one I should be putting the import into, does anyone know?

Also, I'm not sure why there even is the separate project module in my project, intelliJ created it as part of the project.  Could anyone explain the purpose of the two separate modules and why they are there?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You should probably read the SBT tutorial: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Ok, I've figured I to add it to my library dependencies then I recompiled and It correctly fetched and compiled the libraries.  Though I still can't import them into my code, is there a way to make your ide aware of your sbt imported libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in sbt, you have your project. This is specified in build.sbt (or more correctly, any *.sbt file in your projects base directory). Any libraries that your applications code needs, for example, if your application needs to send emails using the commons email library, go in to the librarDependencies seeing in here.

But build.sbt itself is Scala code that needs to be compiled, but it's not part of your applications runtime. So in sbt, your projects build is a project itself, one that has to be compiled. It has its own classpath, which consists of the sbt plugins you're using, so for example, if you need a less compiler to compile your less files, that's not something that gets done at runtime, so you don't want your application code depending on that, it goes into your project builds libraryDependencies, which gets specified in project/plugins.sbt (or in fact any *.sbt in the project directory). So, once you add it there, you can use the Scala code it provides from build.sbt. IntelliJ imports this project for you so that you can have syntax highlighting and other IDE features in build.sbt.

But it doesn't stop there. How does project/plugins.sbt get compiled, where is its classpath? Well, your projects builds projects builds project is also an sbt project itself too... It keeps going down. IntelliJ stops at that point though, it doesn't keep importing these meta sbt projects because it's actually very rare to need additional sbt plugins for your projects builds projects builds project, so it just uses the same classpath as your projects build project for syntax highlighting in project/plugins.sbt.

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation, I understand now!